# SSIS ETL timeout error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

So I am just gonna try out my luck here with a problem that I have been facing with my prod ETL project. It is showing a pattern where it fails every time with a weird error below:

```
Build Dimensions Failed on - BRCSQL-NA1-01.PROD with following Error Messages:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.PreExecute()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
ClientConnectionId:e4461e3d-2a35-42a2-b4da-517602d6c1f3
Enrollment Misc Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80131904.
```

The strange thing is that it just works the second time I would try to run it. So that has been our workaround, I would just go in and rerun it manually whenever I get this error.

It could be something stupid happening with our server maintenance, but I just wanted to make sure with you intelligent people of internet before complaining my server maintenance guys.

Comment: Are the automatic runs on a different machine (perhaps a server)?  It is possible your machine has access to the data source, but the target server does not.  Could be permissions or firewall related.

Comment: @ destination-data. Yeah you are right. But I just realized thats its an intermittent issue. Now it could be some other heavy lifting happening during 11:00 EST when we run our job, but I guess there is no way to be certain. Also correct me if I am wrong there can 100 reasons for this thing to happen. Do you happen to know few at the top of your head which I can check quickly?

Comment: Sure, lots of things could cause that... and it certainly could be performance, since *succeeding the second time* is something it could do, if the first attempt was caching data, that the second time accessed.  Possible *WORKAROUND*.... does it work to make it try a second time on its own?  You could either put a loop in the SSIS tasks, or it might work to put a `TRY...CATCH` right in the T-SQL:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: When you say "re-run it manually", does "manually" mean executing a job stream by starting it in Mgmt Studio, (instead of on a schedule), or executing the SSIS package directly (without the job), or executing the T-SQL directly (without the SSIS package)?

Comment: You could start by changing the job time. If it still fails then it probably isn't another process.  You could also check the server logs, looking at items around 11.